# OCaml - How to change reference

Tags: reference, ocaml

I have a reference:

```
let x = ref 5 ;;
```

And

```
let y = 89;;
```

How to "change" address x that when I do x := 17, then y = 89.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to clarify. You want y to *not* change when you alter the concents of `x`? Lucky you, that's how it works (thank goodness!).

Comment: again, please learn fp and don't use ref.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this question doesn't make sense. Addresses aren't a meaningful concept in OCaml. And y already equals 89.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read the part of the guided tour from Real World OCaml that covers [imperative programming](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/a-guided-tour.html#imperative-programming).  It covers this question and more.